# TSQL case with or in it

Tags: t-sql

My problem:

In my WHERE statement "Shock.Comment" is null-able.
The result i want to achieve is if the parameter

> @missingComments = 1

then i want to get all Shocks that has string empty or null.
What i have TRIED:

```
WHERE Shock.Comment = CASE WHEN @missingComments = 1 THEN '' OR IS NULL END
```

How can i get all posts with comment = null or empty when

> @missingComments = 1

Comment: What should it do when `@missingComment` is not 1?

Comment: Is should skip this where statement. But the problem is that I cant have both '' OR IS NULL its says error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
WHERE (  (@missingComments != 1)
      OR (COALESCE(Shock.Comment, '') = '' )
```

Note that any answer to this using a single static SQL query will not be able to use any indexes on `Shock.Comment` to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is very picky, and can't evaluate to `BIT`, and you can't do `v = A OR B`, you have to do `v = A OR v = B`. This is the solution I came up with.

```
WHERE @missingComment = 0 OR (Shock.Comment = NULL OR Shock.Comment = '')
```